# Android background leaves some white space at bottom

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview

i have a layout in my android project it takes input from edittext and sends the mail from this information but in layout the background does not show up on whole screen it leaves some space at the bottom so it do not look good

this is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"

    >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="530dp"
    android:background="@drawable/f4kf6msk"
    android:fillViewport="true"
      >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="@string/to"
        android:textStyle="bold"
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#6495ed" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/to"
        android:text="@string/app"
        android:textStyle="bold"
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#6495ed" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/from"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

        android:textColor="#6495ed"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/from"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/to"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:textColor="#6495ed"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:hint="@string/too"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
          />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1d"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/message"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/send"
        android:textColor="#6495ed" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/View0dfd1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="3dip"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="#808080"
        android:paddingBottom="3dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/subject"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="23dp"
        android:textColor="#6495ed"
        android:hint="@string/sub1"
         android:textStyle="bold"
        android:ems="10" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/from"
        android:text="@string/sub"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#6495ed"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
        android:text="@string/Message"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#6495ed"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/subject"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:hint="@string/mess"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:lines="11"
        android:textColor="#6495ed"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/View0sd1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="3dip"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button1d"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:background="#808080"
        android:paddingBottom="3dp" />

</RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to put backround in scroll view property instead in relative layout